# Life in a gas torus around a neutron star

Tags: biology, environment, habitability, microgravity

Larry Niven wrote a novel called *The Integral Trees*, which was followed by a sequel *The Smoke Ring*. This is Wikipedia's synopsis of the setting:

> The story occurs around the fictional neutron star Levoy's Star (abbreviated "Voy"). The gas giant Goldblatt's World (abbreviated "Gold") orbits this star just outside its Roche limit and therefore its gravity is insufficient to keep its atmosphere, which is pulled loose into an independent orbit around Voy and forms a ring that is known as a gas torus. The gas torus is huge—one million kilometers thick—but most of it is too thin to be habitable. The central part of the Gas Torus, where the air is thicker, is known as the Smoke Ring. The Smoke Ring supports a wide variety of life.

Two questions:

- **Could such an environment really be habitable to life with similar biochemistry* to Earth's?**
- **Could [abiogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis) occur here? (I doubt it)**

That's more or less it. If you need any more details, just ask in a comment. Also, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees#Setting) is Wikipedia's full description of the novels' setting.

*Edit: by similar, I mean low-temperature carbon-water based life, such that there won't be fundamental changes to biology (e.g. inhaling/exhaling different gases)

Comment: Similar is subjective. What you might say is similar, another person would call different. Especially since you are asking on the chemical scale, the answer is basically always yes

Comment: @Raditz_35 edited to clarify what I meant by similar.

Comment: Why wouldn't abiogenesis occur?  The big problem isn't life, it's evolution--the gas torus won't last long enough.

Comment: Editing your question to invalidate an answer is not exactly appreciated...

Comment: @L.Dutch My apologies, but what else was I to do? You pointed out a more or less fatal flaw in the question, so I either had to edit this one accordingly or ask a new one, leaving your answer on a question that was no longer being asked. If you want, I can revert the edit and ask this in a different question.

Comment: @LorenPechtel From memory the Torus is supposed to last for a few hundred million years all up, that's long enough for evolution, especially considering that nothing native to the Smoke Ring is very advanced.

Comment: I would recommend asking a second question for the neutron star case, @SealBoi.

Comment: @HDE226868 Okay, will do.

Comment: @Ash The Smoke Ring had life far more advanced than Earth at a few hundred million years.  It took Earth more than 2 billion years to reach multi-cellular life, 4 billion to reach what the ring had.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Yes but the smoke ring wouldn't be starting from white hot ball of rock, it has liquid water and an oxygenated atmosphere from day one, which means _some_ life.

Comment: @Ash I was counting from when they figured Earth had cooled enough.  And an oxygen atmosphere is not what you want for abiogenesis!  If it started out with life then Goldblatt's world must have had life, but we see no indication of this.

Comment: @LorenPechtel We see nothing either way as to Goldblatt's, not even speculation. Remember we're not sure that abiogenesis actually _did_ happen on Earth, we don't know what's really needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Could such an environment really be habitable to life with similar biochemistry* to Earth's?

First of all, we should check if the star can emit light. According to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star)

> Neutron stars that can be observed are very hot and typically have a surface temperature of around 600000 K,

which is 100 times the surface temperature of our Sun. This means that the emission is peaked more to the blu-UV region. Not good for life as we know it.

Moreover

> Some neutron stars emit beams of electromagnetic radiation that make them detectable as pulsars,

which I suspect is another hammer blow to the fragility of life.

Further on the same page you can read

> Pulsar planets receive little visible light, but massive amounts of ionizing radiation and high-energy stellar wind, which makes them rather hostile environments.

Therefore my conclusion is that no, it's unlikely that such an environment can host carbon based life.

Comment: Does Niven's implied argument that the torus itself would shelter it's interior from the extremes of the stellar environment hold water or are neutron stars just too hot for atmospheric blocking to be a useful effect?

Comment: You write "neutron stars that can be observed." Why couldn't this be a very very old system with a [very cool neutron star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14387)? I.e. one that would not normally be observed visually. The system might be part of a binary with another star, which is how it would have been discovered.

Comment: A note on the "pulsar" is that the jet of radiation it projected out at the poles and the "smoke ring" would be around the equator.

Comment: A note on the "pulsar" is that the jet of radiation it projected out at the poles and the "smoke ring" would be around the equator.